# Filter an XML document based on a list of ids

Tags: xml, bash

I have a 7GB XML document in the [TREC format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Text_Retrieval_Conference). This file have tags `DOC`, in which there there is `DOCNO` and `TEXT`.

```
<FILE>
<DOC>
<DOCNO>abc</DOCNO>
<TEXT>content
of first
doc</TEXT>
</DOC>
<DOC>
<DOCNO>def</DOCNO>
<TEXT>content
of second
doc</TEXT>
</DOC>
<DOC>
<DOCNO>ghi</DOCNO>
<TEXT>content
of third
doc</TEXT>
</DOC>
</FILE>
```

I want to filter this document and **keep** only `DOC`s that have a `DOCNO` in a **file** containing a list of ids:

```
abc
ghi
```

So the output becomes

```
<FILE>
<DOC>
<DOCNO>abc</DOCNO>
<TEXT>content
of first
doc</TEXT>
</DOC>
<DOC>
<DOCNO>ghi</DOCNO>
<TEXT>content of
third
doc</TEXT>
</DOC>
</FILE>
```

My guess is that `xml_grep` should be useful, but I couldn't do it.

Comment: You could try using `XMLStarlet` to get the `DOC` elements, `awk` to check and print only elements with `DOCNO` equal to `abc, ghi`. Did you try that, or you need it in bash?

Comment: Thanks @tftd. I just want to emphasize that the list of ids is in a file. There are 4 millions of them.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow, you want to get the `DOCNO` content and store it into a file, or you want to get all `DOC` elements where the `DOCNO` contains a certain string? Regarding the length of your file - that's a lot of data. It may take a while to parse and store everything, depending on the system.

Comment: I have 2 input files: 1. an XML document, 2. a file containing a list of `DOCNO`s that I want to keep. The output is a an XML document.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have `xml_grep` I assume that also is installed the [perl](/questions/tagged/perl) module `XML::Twig`. I don't know how `xml_grep` works but you could achieve same result with a complete script, like:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use warnings;
use strict;
use XML::Twig;

XML::Twig->new(
    twig_print_outside_roots => 1,
    twig_roots => {
        'DOC' => sub {
            my $docno = $_->next_elt('DOCNO') || next;
            if ( $docno->text_only =~ m/\A(?:abc|ghi)\Z/ ) { 
                $_->print;
            }   
        },  
    },  
    pretty_print => 'indented',
)->parsefile( shift );
```

It search for every `<DOC>` element, reads the next one and extract its text, that is compared to `abc` or `ghi` using a regular expression, and only print that partial tree in case of a match.

Run it like:

```
perl script.pl xmlfile
```

That yields (note spaces that are not meaningful because they are out of any element):

```
<FILE>

  <DOC>
    <DOCNO>abc</DOCNO>
    <TEXT>content
of first
doc</TEXT>
  </DOC>


  <DOC>
    <DOCNO>ghi</DOCNO>
    <TEXT>content
of third
doc</TEXT>
  </DOC>
</FILE>
```

Comment: Thanks Birei. I do have XML::Twig, but I want to emphasize that the list of ids is in a file. There are 4 millions of them.

Comment: @mossaab: It's trivial to change that issue. Open the file, read it line by line and save each word as key of a hash. Then change the regular expression comparison with a hash check, like: `if ( exists $word{ $docno->text_only } ) { ... }`

Answer (score 2):

Using awk to create the xpath and xmlstarlet to filter the document:

```
$ xpath=$(awk '
            BEGIN {printf "//DOC[not("} 
            {printf "%sDOCNO=\"%s\"", sep, $0; sep=" or "}
            END {print ")]"}
        ' ids.txt)

$ echo "$xpath"
//DOC[not(DOCNO="abc" or DOCNO="ghi")]

$ xmlstarlet ed -O -d "$xpath" file.xml
<FILE>
  <DOC>
    <DOCNO>abc</DOCNO>
    <TEXT>content
of first
doc</TEXT>
  </DOC>
  <DOC>
    <DOCNO>ghi</DOCNO>
    <TEXT>content
of third
doc</TEXT>
  </DOC>
</FILE>
```

Comment: This looks like a working solution. But `xmlstarlet` eats all of the available 12G memory and then hangs. I guess it has to read the whole 7G file before processing it.

Comment: The xpath expression would be quite monstrous too. Better to go with Birei's answer.